# I need help with identifying my 26" cruiser, no ID markings, I built it 25 years ago and could be 15+ years older than that.. TIA

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Bottom bracket and rear brake (click for larger):
[image: Bottom bracket to rear axle]

Bike frame and chainring (click for larger):
[image: head tube and back, chain side]

head tube (click for larger):
[image: head tube]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Do be aware that these questions are extremely difficult to answer. Since any identifying marks have been removed, this may be impossible. There may be some design features that are unique to a certain bike, e.g. some steel Colnago bikes had star-shaped main tubes, and this is a very desirable collectible brand. On less expensive bikes, people are less likely to keep track of the unique features.

Comment: The main way to date a bike is from the components, but if you've replaced a lot of the components then it's a lot harder to guess.  The bottom bracket housing seems a bit large, suggesting that this bike may have been converted from an Astabula crank to the 3-piece.  Which means that we can't use the presence of a square-shaft vs cottered BB to assist in the dating.  The frame is 60s-70s style, but the components appear to be much newer.

Comment: I purchased frame & fork only and the forks aren't original to frame. Added sealed bottom bracket, vintage 3 piece Topline cranks, Chris King, Crupi, Sun Rhyno Lite etc.. Any ideas on maker of Forks would also be appreciated?

Comment: I just found an ID on rear drop out, 00370

Comment: @vlance My guess is that your serial number means it's the 370th Newport frame S&S made. There are several other possible meanings. From what I've seen, smaller frame makers often stamped a number representing total production including that frame as a serial number.

Comment: Thank you David

Answer (score 7):

The frame looks like a 1979 S&S Newport
S&S is the manufacturer.
Newport is the model

It's amazing how many frames similar to this were made from the late 70s to the late 80s (and even some in the 2000s)

[1979 S&S Newport from the BMX Museum](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/sands/103454)
[image]

[Another bike, same frame, different angle, also from the BMX Museum](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/sands/49277)
[image]

Frame only rear shot
[image]

The key frame features are:

- Slightly "notchy" bend in the top tube. Later years(Newport was made until [1983 based on what's posted at the BMX Museum](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/sands/?model=956)) seem to have a smoother bend on the top tube.
- Two piece rear end
- Brake mount made of tubing (not flat steel)
- Flat steel chain stay brace just behind the bottom bracket.
- Straight "3rd tube" brace tube below the top tube.

Comment: found serial # on rear drop out 00370, would this help?

Answer (score 0):

Fork is a 26” Panda fork. I saw another one on a Schwinn Cruiser once.

Comment: Could you add a picture, so it's possible to compare them?